# hidden files and directories warnings

Tags: security, sudo, vim, rkhunter

I received these rkhunter results; what are these files, and are they dangerous?

```
[23:17:48]   Checking for hidden files and directories       [ Warning ]
[23:17:48] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.sudoers.tmp.swl: Vim swap file, version 7.4
[23:17:48] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.sudoers.tmp.swm: Vim swap file, version 7.4
[23:17:48] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.sudoers.tmp.swn: Vim swap file, version 7.4
[23:17:49] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.sudoers.tmp.swo: Vim swap file, version 7.4
[23:17:49] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp: Vim swap file, version 7.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those files are leftovers from you editing the `/etc/sudoers` files with `vim` and not saving the file and exiting the editor properly. Unless you need to recover data from a previous editing session, and unless you are *currently* editing the file, these can be deleted.

See `:help swap-file` in `vim`.